# get whole item from list not just individual letter

Tags: list, javascript

I have this code

```
var listTitle = [];
var listUrl = [];
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listTitle += oListItem.get_item('Title');
    listUrl =  oListItem.get_item('PrivacyStatementUrls').get_url() ;
}
```

I am wanting to put each item of the list as a single item in an array and then make the url the title for each list item like so:

```
    var test = ''

for(i=0; i<listTitle.length;i++)
{

test +='<a href="'+listUrl[i]+'">'+listTitle[i]+'</a>'      
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML =  test;
```

Doing this I found that my code only prints a letter at a time and doesn't place each list item as a single array item.
How can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following:

```
listTitle.push(oListItem.get_item('Title'));
listUrl.push(oListItem.get_item('PrivacyStatementUrls').get_url());
```